# Update scope value when service data is changed

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service in my app:

```
uaInProgressApp.factory('uaProgressService', 
    function(uaApiInterface, $timeout, $rootScope){
        var factory = {};
        factory.taskResource = uaApiInterface.taskResource()
        factory.taskList = [];
        factory.cron = undefined;
        factory.updateTaskList = function() {
            factory.taskResource.query(function(data){
                factory.taskList = data;
                $rootScope.$digest
                console.log(factory.taskList);
            });
            factory.cron = $timeout(factory.updateTaskList, 5000);
        }

        factory.startCron = function () {
            factory.cron = $timeout(factory.updateTaskList, 5000);
        }

        factory.stopCron = function (){
            $timeout.cancel(factory.cron);
        }
        return factory;
});
```

Then I use it in a controller like this:

```
uaInProgressApp.controller('ua.InProgressController',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, uaContext, uaProgressService) {
        uaContext.getSession().then(function(){
            uaContext.appName.set('Testing house');
            uaContext.subAppName.set('In progress');
            uaProgressService.startCron();

            $scope.taskList = uaProgressService.taskList;
        });
    }
);
```

So basically my service update `factory.taskList` every 5 seconds and I linked this `factory.taskList` to `$scope.taskList`. I then tried different methods like `$apply`, `$digest` but changes on `factory.taskList` are not reflected in my controller and view `$scope.taskList`.

It remains empty in my template. Do you know how I can propagate these changes ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

While using `$watch` may solve the problem, it is not the most efficient solution. You might want to change the way you are storing the data in the service.

The problem is that you are replacing the memory location that your `taskList` is associated to every time you assign it a new value while the scope is stuck pointing to the old location. You can see this happening in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TX6w3elHy1bU92XrCRw3?p=preview).

Take a heap snapshots with Chrome when you first load the plunk and, after you click the button, you will see that the memory location the scope points to is never updated while the list points to a different memory location.

You can easily fix this by having your service hold an object that contains the variable that may change (something like `data:{task:[], x:[], z:[]}`). In this case "data" should never be changed but any of its members may be changed whenever you need to. You then pass this data variable to the scope and, as long as you don't override it by trying to assign "data" to something else, whenever a field inside data changes the scope will know about it and will update correctly.

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOzKkqwfQ1P0Uj9BvcQN?p=preview) shows the same example running using the fix suggested above. No need to use any watchers in this situation and if it ever happens that something is not updated on the view you know that all you need to do is run a scope `$apply` to update the view.

This way you eliminate the need for watchers that frequently compare variables for changes and the ugly setup involved in cases when you need to watch many variables. The only issue with this approach is that on your view (html) you will have "data." prefixing everything where you used to just have the variable name.

Comment: What is the reason for the 'new' + iife in the return of the service?

Comment: In this case it would allow you to return a class, removing the new  would break the code. I tend to prefer this structure than the object structure (eg. "{attr:value, attr2:value2...}") since I find it more flexible.  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TX6w3elHy1bU92XrCRw3?p=preview) is the plunker for it, and  [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) is a little info about it from angular team. As you can see you can use service instead of factory for this but either one works fine.

Comment: hey @GabrielPiacenti - you have a really good answer here, I think it would help if you cleaned up the content/formatting a bit...make it more readable...

Comment: Gabriel you should delete most of the code and just have the answer focus on what is needed. You are correct, but this code looks over complicated. Look at the 2 answers below, much cleaner (but they lack the info you have about the memory heap). Nicely done either way!

Comment: I know this is a really old answer, but I've been doing this a ton in my apps and it works like a dream. In Angular 1.5, two way data binding has been removed (mostly), so does this technique fall into the same performance pitfalls that removing two-way data binding set out to solve?

Comment: @Tyler I don't think this should have any performance pitfalls by itself. This is just how object references work in JavaScript and actually in Java also.

Answer (score 72):

Angular (unlike Ember and some other frameworks), does not provide special *wrapped* objects which *semi-magically* stay in sync. The objects you are manipulating are plain javascript objects and just like saying `var a = b;` does not *link* the variables `a` and `b`, saying `$scope.taskList = uaProgressService.taskList` does not link those two values.

For this kind of `link`-ing, `angular` provides [`$watch` on `$scope`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope). You can watch the value of the `uaProgressService.taskList` and update the value on `$scope` when it changes:

```js
$scope.$watch(function () { return uaProgressService.taskList }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.taskList = uaProgressService.taskList;
    }
});
```

The first expression passed to the `$watch` function is executed on every [`$digest` loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) and the second argument is the function which is invoked with the new and the old value.

Comment: Ok I understand so. I tried your snippet and now my app is working as expected :) Does a lot of watch impact app performance?

Comment: Though sometimes [people have had to gone to extreme measures to optimise it](http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/31/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/), it works reasonably well for most apps.

Comment: I was blind for so long, thanks. I thought that because it was a singleton the properties would spread in a magical way :S

Comment: I thought that was not the answer, but I have forget to also watch for change in my model (I have a Controller->Model->Service System)... so when Service Data changed, Controller did not know and doesn't show the change. Also I did think that $scope.$watch('service.var'... would also cause an update :-/.

Comment: I took me literally days to find this answer. Thanks. I'm surprised this use case isn't better documented as this is the only reason I use a service (rpc/pubsub).

Comment: $watch is a hack in this case. The correct technique is described by the other two answers, specially @Gabriel Piacenti

Comment: @Alkaline I would consider that a matter of opinion/design/taste. In this particular case (i.e. when the programmer has control over what the service provides), I too would consider keeping the controller light weight and changing the service to provide a nested dictionary. However, in some cases, the other solutions are not available to the users and adding a watch may be **least-code-to-maintain** fix.

Comment: $watch is being abused to death by Angular newcomers and the case described is classic. It's actually due to how javascript works. The binding would work if the user would not replace the reference to the array (factory.taskList = data;) but instead modifies factory.taskList (using slice, lodashjs, etc). The updating is done automatically by Angular. No need to add an additional watch.

Answer (score 45):

I'm not sure if thats help but what I am doing is bind the function to $scope.value. For example

```
angular
  .module("testApp", [])
  .service("myDataService", function(){
    this.dataContainer = {
      valA : "car",
      valB : "bike"
    }
  })
  .controller("testCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    "myDataService",
    function($scope, myDataService){
      $scope.data = function(){
        return myDataService.dataContainer;
      };
  }]);
```

Then I just bind it in DOM as

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in data() "></li>
```

This way you can avoid to using $watch in your code.

Comment: **BEST ANSWER** ignore the $watch answers this is how it should be done. The above has it correct as well, but is extremely confusing.

Comment: Sorry to bring up a an old answer, but this solution works perfectly for me and I'm wondering if there are any drawbacks to it that I need to be aware of? I've tried various ways of linking scopes and services but no solution is any where near as elegant as this.

Comment: Sorry for late response. This shouldn't be use in cases where your data function is quite complex. Each time when the $digest run, the method will be invoked.

Comment: To resolve that problem use a factory, it returns the value and it updates itself when the data is changed.

Comment: I wish I could thank you more than just saying thanks..!! couldn't find any solution, even watch didn't work for me for some weird reason but this one does its job! THANK YOU!

Comment: late but wondering why when we do console.log($scope.data) it does not get logged, but the DOM element still shows the updated value. Is it because the service is a separate scope from the controller scope? would we need to define data as  a ng-model to make console log work?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel not sure what you mean, but if you set log in your js outside of method which is executed under digest/apply then this runs only once. Angular execute $scope.data because is bind to DOM which is recalculated on apply/digest

Answer (score 5):

No `$watch` or etc. is required. You can simply define the following

```
uaInProgressApp.controller('ua.InProgressController',
  function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, uaContext, uaProgressService) {
    uaContext.getSession().then(function(){
        uaContext.appName.set('Testing house');
        uaContext.subAppName.set('In progress');
        uaProgressService.startCron();
    });

    $scope.getTaskList = function() {
      return uaProgressService.taskList;
    };
  });
```

Because the function `getTaskList` belongs to `$scope` its return value will be evaluated (and updated) on every change of `uaProgressService.taskList`

Answer (score 3):

Lightweight alternative is that during controller initialization you subscribe to a notifier pattern set up in the service.

Something like:

```
app.controller('YourCtrl'['yourSvc', function(yourSvc){
    yourSvc.awaitUpdate('YourCtrl',function(){
        $scope.someValue = yourSvc.someValue;
    });
}]);
```

And the service has something like:

```
app.service('yourSvc', ['$http',function($http){
    var self = this;
    self.notificationSubscribers={};
    self.awaitUpdate=function(key,callback){
        self.notificationSubscribers[key]=callback;
    };
    self.notifySubscribers=function(){
        angular.forEach(self.notificationSubscribers,
            function(callback,key){
                callback();
            });
    };
    $http.get('someUrl').then(
        function(response){
            self.importantData=response.data;
            self.notifySubscribers();
        }
    );
}]);
```

This can let you fine tune more carefully when your controllers refresh from a service.

Comment: As a note, I've since found a much more effective solution to this. Use nested routes with Angular UI router and place all the long lived event notifiers in the root controller.

Comment: I wanted to be able to place a list of data anywhere, and got inspired by your answer to write a directive that makes use of a service based on your subscribe principle. I think that at directive is a much more simpel solution than nested routes. But I guess it depends... anyway, thank you for providing a very nice and useful piece of code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Like Gabriel Piacenti said, no watches are needed if you wrap the changing data into an object.

> BUT for updating the changed service data in the scope correctly, it is important that the scope value of the controller that uses the service data does not point directly to the changing data (field). Instead the scope value must point to the object that wraps the changing data.

The following code should explain this more clear. In my example i use an NLS Service for translating. The NLS Tokens are getting updated via http.

The Service:

```
app.factory('nlsService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var data = {
    get: {
      ressources        : "gdc.ressources",
      maintenance       : "gdc.mm.maintenance",
      prewarning        : "gdc.mobMaint.prewarning",
    }
  };
// ... asynchron change the data.get = ajaxResult.data... 
  return data;
}]);
```

Controller and scope expression

```
app.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, nlsService)
  {
    $scope.NLS = nlsService;
  }
);

<div ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
  <span class="navPanelLiItemText">{{NLS.get.maintenance}}</span>
</div>
```

The above code works, but first i wanted to access my NLS Tokens directly (see the following snippet) and here the values did not become updated.

```
app.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, nlsService)
  {
    $scope.NLS = nlsService.get;
  }
);

<div ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
  <span class="navPanelLiItemText">{{NLS.maintenance}}</span>
</div>
```