# Update scope value when service data changes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update the scope value on a view when the service data changes.

The problem is that, (a) if I update the data in a different controller, then (b) the value doesn't update on the view.

main.html

```
<!-- breadcrumb row -->
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <span ng-if="memberCompany !== null">{{ memberCompany }}</span>
</div>
<!-- / breadcrumb -->
```

main.js

```
// breadcrumb service
app.service('breadcrumb', function() {

    // variables
    var memberCompany = null;

    return {
        // get compnay
        getCompany: function() {
            return memberCompany;
        },
        // set company
        setCompany: function(value) {
            memberCompany = value;
        }
    }
});

// main controller
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'breadcrumb', function($scope, breadcrumb) {

        // get company to display in view
        $scope.memberCompany = breadcrumb.getCompany();
    }
]);
```

If I update the service value in a different controller, I would like to be able to display that updated value back on the index view so it's viable across the app

other controller

```
app.controller('otherController', ['$scope', 'breadcrumb', function($scope, breadcrumb) {

    // update company
    breadcrumb.setCompany('StackExchange');

    // update the scope data in the view?   

}]);
```

How can I display the updated value on the index view once it's changed?

Comment: Set a `$watch` in your controller on that service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update scope value when service data is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744462/update-scope-value-when-service-data-is-changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `$watch` in your controller on that service:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return breadcrumb.getCompany()
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.memberCompany = newValue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a site-wide necessity, I would definitely stay far, far away from adding a bunch of watches everywhere as they can be costly for development time as well as computer resources. I would first write the service accordingly:

```
angular.module('myModule').service('Breadcrumb', function() {
  return {
    company: null,
    setCompany: function(company) {
      this.company = company;
    },
    getCompany: function() {
      return this.company;
    }
  };
});
```

Although in my opinion, the getters and setters are definitely very unnecessary ( you could just set by `Breadcrumb.company = company` and get by `Breadcrumb.company`). Moving on, you should assign the breadcrumb service to the root scope:

```
angular.module('myModule').run(function($rootScope, Breadcrumb) {
  return $rootScope.breadcrumb = Breadcrumb;
});
```

Then at this point you can either inject this service into your controllers/directives and call upon it within any view in the application like so:

```
<span class="my-company-name" ng-bind="$root.breadcrumb.company.name" />
```

This saves you from having to call watchers on everything and allows for you to only inject the `Breadcrumb` service when you actually need it in the application logic. However, like I said at first, it really depends on how widely used this service is as you do not want to muddy up your `$rootScope` with arbitrary values. If you don't want to assign it to the `$rootScope` you could assign it in your controllers and directives:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('ApplicationCtrl', function($scope, Breadcrumb) {
  $scope.breadcrumb = Breadcrumb;
});
```

and access it from templates like this:

```
<span ng-bind="breadcrumb.company.whatever" />
```

Hope that helps!