# Correct way of listening to changes in factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller, MapController and a factory, controlService. controlService has objects with boolean values that are modified by a different controller. Currently, whenever a control's boolean checked value is changed, MapController runs a function on the control using $watch as follows:

```
$scope.$watch((function() {
        return controlService.getDrawControl().checked;
    }), function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
            vm.draw(newVal);

        }
    });
```

How do I achieve this same behavior following the recommendation in this answer to a similar question: [Update scope value when service data is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744462/update-scope-value-when-service-data-is-changed/27501691#27501691)

I'm confused on how the value stays updated, and on top of that, how to run a function each time the view associated with the MapController is loaded based on that value.

Comment: Instead of using a watcher, you could broadcast an event from the service every time its state changes, and listen to this event in the controller.

Comment: I originally implemented this using events, but from what I understand using events is less 'angular' than using something like $watch. In other words, I'm trying to understand all of the ways to do this.

Comment: Well, I disagree. The advantage of an event is that it doesn't need to constantly check, at each digest iteration, if the watched expression/function has changed. You only receive a notification when the specific service state has changed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input...good point.