# Update HTML when scope changes inside a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an html element which I would like to update upon different actions.

HTML

```
<span>{{progress.mandates_transferred}}/{{progress.mandates_count}}</span>
```

js

```
    this.app.controller('appController', ['MandateService', function(MandateService){
    MandateService.progress($scope)

    $scope.MarkDone = function() {
      MandateService.progress($scope)
    }

}])
   this.app.service('MandateService' [
    '$http',
    function($http) {
      var url = 'api/mandate'
      return {
        progress: function($scope) {
             $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
             $scope.progress = data
        })
                  }
      }}])
```

There is a click action markDone which calls the MandateService to update the $scope values

the value $scope.progress updates if I add a console.log in the service to check the values in $scope but it is not updated in the HTML.
I have tried a few techniques mentioned but none of them help

I have tried adding $scope.$apply() but I get an error $digest already in progress
[sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26168370/1087841)
[sol2](https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2014/6/2/How-do-I-run-code-when-a-variable-changes-with-angularjs)

Comment: Return a promise from your service to your controller and resolve it there with your $scope

Comment: ok let me try these suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You should not be accessing $scope inside a service, but rather have your service function return data that you will update your $scope with, in your controller.

```
this.app.controller('appController', ['MandateService', function(MandateService) {

    $scope.MarkDone = function() {
        $scope.progress = MandateService.progress();
    }

}]);


this.app.service('MandateService' ['$http', function($http) {
        var url = 'api/mandate'
        return {
            progress: function() {
                $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                    return data;
                })
            }
        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$broadcast`, try this:

```
this.app.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$rootScope','MandateService', function($scope, $rootScope, MandateService){
    MandateService.progress($scope)

    $scope.MarkDone = function() {
      MandateService.progress($scope)
    }

    $rootScope.$on('progress_update', function(event, data){
      $scope.progress = data.progress;
    });

}])

this.app.service('MandateService' ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
  var url = 'api/mandate'
  return {
    progress: function() {
         $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('progress_update', {progress: data});
        });
    }
}}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct and will achieve the same end result, I would suggest using callbacks within services, might be my personal habit, but it makes the code much cleaner in my opinion (Of course if you don't make spaghetti out of it and end up in thousands of callbacks, then your code will be unreadable).

```
this.app.controller('appController', ['MandateService', function(MandateService)   {  

    $scope.progress = {};

    $scope.MarkDone = function() {  
         MandateService.progress(function(data){
            $scope.progress = data;
         })
    }

}]) 

this.app.service('MandateService'['$http', function($http)   {  
   var url = 'api/mandate' 
   return {  
      progress:function(callback) {  
         $http.get(url).success(function(data) {  
           callback(data);
         })
      }
   }
}])
```

A callback in a service.. you pass a function which will be called once the $http.get completes and returns variable data back to the calling function. Simple & Effective.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not really updates the HTML, although the new values are in the scope

Comment: @Saad First define the scope variable before you assign the value (See my edit).

Comment: I tried that and I am getting this error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: @Saad That's correct. I edited my comment and answer.

Comment: I have tried that but inside the 
    MandateService.progress(function(data){
            $scope.progress = data;
           console.log($scope.progress)
         })
the value is correct
but outside the value of $scope.progress still does not change

Comment: Did you define the $scope.progress = {}; outside the function? What data is your request returning?

Comment: Yes I did define the scope and it is returning a JS object.